# Handle expiry credits in a transaction table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, database-schema

Consider table `Credits`

```
 CREATE TABLE `Credits` (
  `UserID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Amount` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `Expire` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '9999-12-31 23:59:59'
)
```

With data:

```
UserID    Amount    Created       Expire
1         10        2016-01-14    2016-05-30
1         -2        2016-02-04    9999-12-31
1         3         2016-06-01    2016-09-30
```

Without the **Expiry** handing, to get the current amount of a user, it can be handled by a simple select

```
 SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM Credits WHERE UserID = 1;
```

Now, I need to write a SELECT query, with an input parameter of date, and able to get the usable amount of credits at that time, like the following..

At..

- 2016-01-15 => 10
- 2016-02-06 => 8
- 2016-05-31 => 0
- 2016-06-03 => 3

Is it possible with just the above schema? Or I need to add extra field?

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a52b/3

Comment: Please show the code that does the updating. Please read about MCVEs in the help center.

Comment: There's something of a design trap here.  If someone has credits that expire on different dates, you need some sort of logic to work out exactly which credits were consumed - it matters, because the expiry could produce different balance outcomes depending on which credits were selected.  If expenditures can be refunded, this becomes even messier.

Comment: @JeffreyHantin, you are right, so for this question I am also looking for any design improvement can be done..

Comment: @Ryan, I've added an answer.

Answer (score 2):

When you make transaction with negative `Amount`, you should find corresponding transaction with positive `Amount` and set same expiration date. So that, you store expiration date of credits you spend. Your example table will look like this:

```
UserID    Amount    Created       Expire
1         10        2016-01-14    2016-05-30
1         -2        2016-02-04    2016-05-30
1         3         2016-06-01    2016-09-30
```

That makes query for balance on any particular date look as following:

```
SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM Credits WHERE UserID = 1 and @date between Created and Expire;
```

Notice, you may have to split one transaction with negative amount to cover credits with different expiration date. For example, you have following table:

```
UserID    Amount    Created       Expire
1         10        2016-01-14    2016-05-30
1         10        2016-02-04    2016-06-30
```

and you want to make transaction with `Amount=-15`, then you need to make two records:

```
UserID    Amount    Created       Expire
1         -10       2016-04-26    2016-05-30
1         -5        2016-04-26    2016-06-30
```

To find out not yet spend or expired credits along with their expiration date, you can use following query:

```
select sum(Amount) as Amount, Expire
from Credits
where UserID = 1 and curdate() <= Expire
group by Expire
having sum(Amount) > 0
order by Expire
```

Comment: Thanks, what if, the amount needed to spend is not `-15`, but `5`, for example? Only partial positive credits are spent..

Comment: @Ryan Then, assuming you want to spend sooner expiring credits first, you make one record `UserID=1, Amount=-5, Created=2016-04-26, Expire=2016-05-30`.

Answer (score 2):

There's something of a design trap here. If someone has credits that expire on different dates, you need some sort of logic to work out exactly which credits were consumed - it matters, because the expiry could produce different balance outcomes depending on which credits were selected. If expenditures can be refunded, this becomes even messier.

Therefore, I suggest breaking this up into two tables.  I have also taken the liberty of making some fields `NOT NULL` without `DEFAULT` - that is, making them mandatory to supply on INSERT - and dropping the identifier quoting for clarity.

```
CREATE TABLE Transactions (
  TransactionID int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Timestamp datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  Caption nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (TransactionID)
)

CREATE TABLE Credits (
  UserID int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  Amount int(11) NOT NULL,
  Expire datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '9999-12-31 23:59:59',
  ProducingTransactionID int(11) unsigned NOT NULL REFERENCES ,
  ConsumingTransactionID int(11) unsigned NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (UserID, Amount, Expire, ProducingTransaction),
  INDEX (UserID, ConsumingTransaction, Expire),
  FOREIGN KEY (SourceTransactionID) REFERENCES Transactions (TransactionID),
  FOREIGN KEY (SinkTransactionID) REFERENCES Transactions (TransactionID),
)
```

The idea here is that transactions are forced to be explicit about exactly which credits they are affecting, and these explicit choices are recorded.  Credits cannot be added without a link back to the `SourceTransactionID` they are sourced from; when credits are used, the `SinkTransactionID` is simply populated with a link to the transaction in which they are used, and only credits where `SinkTransactionID` is null are potentially available balance.

Note that a `Credits` row should not be updated in any way other than to set `SinkTransactionID`, and therefore cannot be partially consumed by each of multiple transactions - instead, a transaction that wants to sink only part of a `Credits` row needs to insert a new `Credits` row containing the "change" on the partially used row and referencing itself as the source.

Point-in-time balance queries become slightly more complex, since now you have to join `Transactions` to filter out transactions that occurred after the intended point-in-time.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(t.Amount) 
from (select case amount 
             when current_date>expiry_date then 1
             else 0
             end as amount
      FROM Credits WHERE UserID ＝ 1 AND Expire <= CURDATE()
     )t.
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've updated my question with more detail instruction and 4 test cases, will you able to re-visit it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN SUM(c.amount) > 0 then SUM(c.amount) else 0 end as total_amount
FROM Credits c 
where c.userId = 1 and c.Expire <= CURDATE() -- or any date
```

[Sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/170b3/11).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've updated my question with more detail instruction and 4 test cases, will you able to re-visit it? Thanks